# 3-Legged Oauth for GetGlue API

Tags: php, api, oauth

I've been trying for a while to use Oauth to connect to the GetGlue API, with no success what so ever.
I've downloaded every library I can find (like oauth-php) and tried every example I could find on the internet. There MUST be an example for an Oauth connection to the GetGlue API somewhere, but I cant seem to find it. Anyone have any experience with this. Maybe some samplecode even?

Note: All I need is a single request for my own account. I've tried to stay clear of DB sollutions because it's not at all neccesary since it's just going to be my account that has data to be saved.

Comment: seriously? nobody? someone has to know about 3legged oauth?

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetGlue is switching/has switched to [OAuth 2.0](http://developer.getglue.com/#authentication) for authentication. You might be more successful with it. The authentication flow follows [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2) closely.

Once you registered your app on their [OAuth 2.0 portal](https://api.getglue.com/oauth2/) and obtained a client id and secret, do something along the lines of:

Load the authorize URL to let the user authorize your app:

```
// remove the line breaks!
https://api.getglue.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code
&scope=public+read+write
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&client_id=<your OAuth client id>
```

Once the user has authorized your app, GetGlue will redirect to the given redirect_uri with a code query parameter you have to intercept, e.g.

```
http://localhost&code=<auth code>
```

Pass that code to the token endpoint to get an access token to append as a query parameter when accessing the v3 API:

```
// get tokens
https://api.getglue.com/oauth2/access_token?client_secret=<OAuth client secret>&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=ttp://localhost&code=<auth code>&client_id=<OAuth client id>
```

If successful this will return some JSON. Be aware that they redirect from HTTPS to HTTP there. Some HTTP clients refuse to do this.

```
{
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "access_token":"<an access token>",
   "scope":"public read write",
   "expires_in":5184000, // in seconds from now
   "refresh_token":"<a refresh token>"
}
```

Pass the access_token as a query parameter when making API calls. If the access_token has expired, call the token endpoint with the refresh_token as auth code to get a new one. If that fails, you have to make the user authorize your app again.

There is also a [Java library (getglue-java)](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/getglue-java) for the new API now.

Answer (score 0):

For GetGlue, you have send email to obtain the Consumer Key and Secret and thus, if you have the both then I can easily help you. I will provide you all the details to do..

Comment: I actually already have the keys from getglue, just cant get oauth to work