# How do I authenticate a GetGlue user?

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0

I've been racking my brain, and all though other people have asked on this site and received no answers, I figured I would try as well.

I have a GetGlue oAuth2 App with a consumer_key and consumer_secret. They only provide 2 URLs in their documentation:
http://developer.getglue.com/#authentication

I need to allow users to connect their GetGlue accounts to our web app. All I need is the users getglue ID, so I can check the API, but the documentation is insanely terrible.

Please help. I was able to do the same with FourSquare, Facebook, Twitter and Instagram perfectly fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19624222/1000543.

In short: they switched to OAuth 2.0, so you need to [register your app](https://api.getglue.com/oauth2/) again to get an OAuth 2.0 client id and secret.